# Append class to posts page

Tags: posts, blog, body-class

I'm trying to style something unique to the Blog/Posts page, which isn't on the front page. The body tag right now looks like this:`<body <?php body_class() ?>>`

But doing this `<body <?php body_class('blog') ?>>` only returns `<body class="logged-in">` or just `<body>` if I'm not logged in.


I've tried:

```
<body <?php if ( is_home()) {
    echo 'class="blog"';
} else {
    body_class(); }?>>
```

It sort of works but it replaces the "logged-in" class entirely. There has to be a way to append classes to the body tag for posts pages right?

Comment: Note that posts page should have `blog` class by default. If it doesn't you might have theme or something else messing up context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's functions file, use the `body_class` filter to add new classes:

```
function wpse_282694_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $classes[] = 'blog';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_282694_body_class' );
```

If your category archives, tag archives, date archives and search results also need the same styling, which is fairly commin, check for each of them like so:

```
if ( is_home() || is_date() || is_tag() || is_category() || is_search() ) {}
```

Note that I didn't use `is_archive()`, because that would also affect any custom post types you might be using.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your class as argument

```
<body <?php if ( is_home()) { body_class('my-class'); } else { body_class(); }?>>
```

Comment: This works for other pages but not the Latest Posts Page.

Comment: Check edited answer